# @gorhom-react-native-bottom-sheet | How to logout user's current snapPoint value?

Tags: react-native, bottom-sheet, scroll-snap-points

there is **no problem** with **react-native-bottom-sheet** itself, all works as intended.
But I'm wondering - if I provide three snapPoints values ie ['50%', '75%', '90%'] is it possible to logout  specific value being currently used on user's screen?
Something to check how many times he is opening bottom-sheet to the '90%'

I tried to logout currently used snapPoint, but it looks like my app is passing all snapPoints to the library. Do I have to modify the library itself to get the data on specific snapPoint being used?